# How to put an image for submit button

Tags: html, css

I want to change the submit button to an image but, I need its value to be the one I get from the database.

```
<input type="image" src="images/icon_edit.gif" >
<input name="SID" type="radio" value="<? echo $row['ID']; ?>">
```

I currently have it so I have to check the radio button before I can click the image witch is the submit button. Is there a way so I can just have the image and have its value be from what I pull from the database so I don't need the radio button I have to check before I send it to the next page?

Comment: where is your submit button in code?

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala whenever i click the image, it acts as the submit button

Comment: so what exactly you require? where is the code that converts image to button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set the background using css, then you can use a regular input[type=submit] and have the value of your choice.

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="<? echo $row['ID']; ?>">
```

CSS

```
input[type=submit] {
  background:url(images/icon_edit.gif);
}
```

Probs need to change the url to the image but otherwise should be good to go! :-)

Comment: To quote the original question "I want to change the submit button to an image"

Comment: the question is not well explained...you should clarify the question before answering it.

Comment: True, but the logic used here could be applied to any number of html elements.

Comment: @Cesarg219 what do you mean by not changing it?

Comment: You will need to change the path to the image because the path is now relative to you CSS's location, not your php page

Comment: @bantman this file and the css file are in the same location. what else could it be?

Comment: I would try making the element display:block and giving it a height and width. So... `display:block; height:100px; width:100px;`

Comment: @bantman I ended getting the correct file path for the image but the "<? echo $row['ID']; ?>" writes the number on top of it and breaking the image theres no way to keep the value and just not display the value?

Comment: You could just get rid of the php. And leave the value blank... `<input type="submit" value="">`

Comment: @bantman if i leave it blank my php code doesnt know who was selected and it leaves all the fields blank

Comment: Try adding this to your css for the button `text-indent:-9999px;`, it will leave the value intact but you won't be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS background image to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

May be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#imgSubmitButton").click(function () {
        $("#formName").submit();
    });
}); 
</script>

<form id="formName" name="formName" action="xxx.php" method="post">
    <img src="icon_edit.gif" id="imgSubmitButton" style="cursor:pointer">
    <input name="SID" type="radio" value="<? echo $row['ID']; ?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit">
<img src="xyz.png" width="50" height="50">
</button>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not recommended. Please explain your answer.